# Converting an MySQL Date to friendly string.

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date stored in a MySWL database in the following format.

2011-08-23 00:00:00

I'm then pulling that date in with php like so

```
echo $row['start'];
```

I want to edit the PHP code to display the date in the following format.

08/16/2011 12:00 am

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer:

```
echo date('m/d/Y g:ia',strtotime($row['start']));
```

Answer (score 2):

date_format is your friend.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
select date_format('2011-08-23 00:00:00','%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p') -- 08/23/2011 12:00 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse the timestamp stored by MySQL with `strtotime` to a unix timestamp, then use the `date` function to format it.

`echo date('m/d/Y g:ia', strtotime($row['start']));`